# Does $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac1{x^2}$equal $\infty$ or does it not exist?

Tags: limits

If  $\ f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R\ $  where  $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ then $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=?$$

Which of the following option is most correct among these

(a)$\infty$

(b) **limit does not exists**

*Solution*

According to me$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\infty$$

but the limit is not finite so we can say that the **limit does not exists**

*I am confused to choose the option among (a) & (b) in single choice type question*

**Can anyone tell me ?**

Comment: Note that $f$ as given is not a function, as it is not defined at $0\in\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Negative part isn't in the domain of $x^2$ so b is more appropriate

Answer (score 3):

The limit in fact does not exist, as $\infty$ is not a value but more a kind of expression. But I think everyone will know that by saying $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\infty$ you mean $f(x) \to \infty$ for $x\to 0$.

When beginning to work with limits it is didactically-wise more meaningful to use the the latter, but later on it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

The limit does not exist in the sense that there is **no real number $L$** for which the formal definition of $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to a$ (with $a=0$ in your case) is satisfied; you have probably seen this $\varepsilon \; \delta$-definition and if a function satisfies it, the following notation is used:
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$

Usually however, the concept of limits is **generalized** to capture some other kinds of (limit) behavior. One of those is $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to a$. Note that this has a different formal definition. Your example satisfies this definition, so if you have seen this generalization: it will be the answer and the following notation is introduced:
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = +\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

*Technically*, (b) is the most correct. However, we've invented a shorthand for the times when the function grows larger and larger without coming back down as $x \to 0$. That shorthand is written $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = \infty$. Keep in mind, though, that it is a shorthand, and it *means* that for any $N>0$, we may find a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)| > N$ for all $0<|x|<\delta$. That is a fundamentally different statement from $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = L$ for any finite $L$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x \geq \delta$

Comment: @Gathdi No. This is the limit as $x \to 0$, so we are setting an _upper bound_ for $x$ that lets us say that $f(x)$ is large enough.

Comment: @Gathdi There should, however, have been absolute value signs on my $x$. That has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is correct, the definition  says that a limit of a function $f$ does not exists if and only if doesn't exists the limite finite in $\mathbb R$ and the limit $\pm\infty$. So $lim_{x\to x_0 }f=l$ exists if $l \in \mathbb R, $ or $l= \pm\infty$. Hope this help you.

Comment: but which option will be correct to choose among them? c an you tell me

Comment: According to the  classic definition the correct option is (a).

Comment: whats wrong with the option **b** if w choose ti instead of **a**

Comment: I think it is wrong because i'm appealling to the definition that i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

**Usually** we say that a limit exists if it is equal to a number. This is the convention used in, for example, Stewart's Calculus book. Infinity ($\infty$) is not a number and so if a limit is equal to $\infty$, then it does not exist. With this convention the answer is (a) and (b).

Now, this is the standard convention, but there are probably books/notes/teachers who use other conventions. So to accurately answer your question, you need to ask your teacher or consult your textbook/notes.